# Why parallel is slower than normal in my Python code?

Tags: python

I would like to test parallel code with Python, so I wrote the following code.

```
__author__ = 'Zir'
import numpy as np
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import time

def f(x):
    h = np.random.rand()
    return x + h

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s1 = time.time()
    y = Parallel(n_jobs=3)(delayed(f)(x) for x in range(100000))
    e1 = time.time() - s1
    s2 = time.time()
    y = []
    for x in range(100000):
        y.append(f(x))
    e2 = time.time() - s2
    print e1, e2
```

The output is this: `4.08599996567 0.0699999332428` which says that the for loop is much faster. Why?

Comment: Have you tried with f that takes more time?

Comment: @Kira: There is overhead associated with creating the processes.  The simpler your function is, the more likely it is that that overhead will outweigh the cost of actually computing the function.